# custom class sql query class to transfer selected record from one db.table to another

Tags: java, sql

i am trying to transfer records of a selected person into another table. I have a jcombobox that is filled with names of people.(which I wrote an sql query for).the following code populates my comobox named comboNames:

```
private void getNames(){

    try{
    String sql = "select ID,NAME,MIDDLENAME,SURNAME from table1";
    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
    String id = rs.getString("ID");String name = rs.getString("NAME");String middlename = rs.getString("MIDDLENAME"); String surname = rs.getString("SURNAME");
    String fullname = id+" "+name+" "+middlename+" "+surname;
    comboNames.addItem(fullname);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    finally{
   try{
  rs.close();
   pst.close();
   }
   catch(Exception e){
                   }
  }

    }
```

and when a name is selected from the list in the comboBox I used string tokenizer to get only the id into a label called person_id.
my problem is I wrote the sql query that will transfer the records in another class. and that class must get the value in the jlabel named 'person_id' which is another class before the value can be transferred.below is the other class written for the transfer method.

```
public class transfer_person {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public String getID;

 publictransfer_person (){
 con = myKIDS.connectKids();
 }
 public void insertID(){
 this.getID=Transfer.displayID.getText();

 }
 public void makeTransfer(){   
try{
     String sql = "Insert into table2(ID,NAME,MIDDLENAME,SURNAME,OLD_ARREARS,DATE,CONTACT) Select ID,NAME,MIDDLENAME,SURNAME,OLD_ARREARS,DATE,CONTACT from table1 where ID='"+getID+"'";
     pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
     pst.execute();
}catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
 finally{
   try{
  rs.close();
   pst.close();
   }
   catch(Exception e){
                   }
   }

            try{
                String sql ="delete from table1 where ID='"+getID+"'";
                pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.execute();
            }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

            }finally{
                try{
                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                }
            }
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"student / pupil with id :"+getID+" repeated to Form 2 Successfully.");

}
}
```

and this is the method when the button in the other jframe is clicked:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    Repeat_student rsp = new Repeat_student();
    rsp.insertID();
    rsp.makeTransfer();

    }
```

the problem is, the other class is unable to get the value of the jlabel(person_id) in the jframe hence the query cant work. please what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

ok i have it solved.. I wrote this in addition to what I had in my transfer_person class:

```
this.getID=Transfer.displayID.getText();
```

thanks to all who read my post.. may you stay blessed as always.